# tikzmarknode and vphantom take up horizontal space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikzmark, phantom

A `tikzmarknode` combined with a `vphantom` character takes up horizontal space.  Minimal but nonetheless noticeable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
Text \tikzmarknode{a}text

Text \tikzmarknode{b}text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  \draw (a.west) -- (b.west); \end{tikzpicture}

Text \tikzmarknode{a}{\vphantom{t}}text

Text \tikzmarknode{b}{\vphantom{t}}text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  \draw (a.west) -- (b.west); \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyone able to explain why? 
And is there a way to either prevent that or at least to figure out what the exact space is so I can fix it somehow?

Comment: The problem is not the \vphantom, but that the argument has not width. Compare with `\tikzmarknode{a}{}` instead of leaving out the second argument (which then picks up the t).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't quite understand.  Both `{}` and the `vphantom` give me the little extra space.  My goal of using `vphantom` was to control the vertical anchor "west" of the node, without using up horizontal space.

Comment: Yes as I said, both cases introduce a 1pt box. But I don't have the time to look now why, perhaps later.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you are sure it's always exactly 1pt, I could control for it with a negative `hspace`?  ... but still curious as to what exactly is going on here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `minimum width` which has the value 1pt (the documentation seems to be wrong here). Probably tikzmark should better set it to 0pt in the \tikzmarknode, make a bug report.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={minimum width=0pt}}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}

Text \tikzmarknode{a}text

Text \tikzmarknode{b}text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  \draw (a.west) -- (b.west); \end{tikzpicture}

Text \tikzmarknode{a}{\vphantom{t}}text

Text \tikzmarknode{b}{\vphantom{t}}text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  \draw (a.west) -- (b.west); \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've submitted a bugreport on github, thank you :)

Comment: The default of `1pt` for `minimum width` is set in the TikZ/pgf code, not the `tikzmark` code.  `tikzmark` doesn't explicitly set `minimum width`.  Do you think that it ought to?  This feels like an edge case in that *usually* `\tikzmarknode` will have some contents, and thus some width.  That said, it does explicitly set `inner sep` to `0pt` so for consistency perhaps there's a case for `minimum width` to be explicitly set to `0pt` and then `every tikzmarknode/.style` used to override that.  I'm not sure which way to go here.

Comment: @LoopSpace imho it would be sensible if tikzmarknode would set locally `minimum width` to 0pt. 1pt doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree that if I'm to set it in `\tikzmarknode` then `0pt` makes more sense than `1pt`. I'm just not sure that there's a case for `\tikzmarknode` to set it at all.

Comment: (I'm also not sure that there *isn't* a case, either.)

Comment: @LoopSpace the example here is a case: I can't see who would expect a \tikzmarknode with an empty argument to give an 1pt box.